# Selenium - Passing multiple paramaters to @Test method using data provider which reads excel file

Tags: excel, selenium, testng

My @Test method takes input from an excel work book. The input values are categorized in several work sheets. The total number of input values are more than 50. How to pass this excel data with several sheets to the @Test method as i can't define all the parameters in the @Test method as arguments. Please help.

Comment: You'll can use a tool like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) to read the Excel file.

Comment: It has to be Exel file, or is csv will be ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Data.OleDb and use it in someway like this....

```
public static DataSet actual_read(string filename)
        {
            var conn = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", filename);
            DataSet allSheetVal = new DataSet();
            string[] sheets = GetExcelsheetNames(conn);
            //bool isspace = false;
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
            {
                con.Open();
                foreach (string sheet in sheets)
                {
                    string[] spsheet = sheet.Split(' ');
                    int toSub = (spsheet.Count() > 1) ? 2 : 1;
                    string sheetName = sheet;
                    if (sheetName[sheetName.Length - toSub] != '$')
                    {
                        if (toSub == 2)
                        {
                            sheetName = sheetName.Substring(0, (sheetName.Length - 1));
                            sheetName += "$'";
                        }
                        else
                            sheetName += '$';
                    } 
                    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", con);
                    var ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds, sheetName);
                    allSheetVal.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[sheetName].Copy());
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return allSheetVal;
        }
```

so that it will return a DataSet then you can read it....(note each sheet is treated as a table in this execution)